# Connect to SQL Server from different network (remote)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am new to SQL server stuff and recently thought of creating a Database for my website. I would like to stop things like comments, blog post, stuff like that. But I am trying not to pay for SQL server space. I have although a copy of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 which I have created a db and table from which I can access via a C# program I have made. Now, I am facing the program where if I am not connect to the same network as the SQL Server PC, I can no longer connect. Is there a way for me to make my SQL Server available to all people? So say if I am on my phone and want to log-in to my SQL Server, can I?

Basically the root of my question is: Can I, with SSMS, create a public SQL Server which can be remotely connected to via other internet connections. If I cannot, can only recommended me software that can? I have bought a computer on sale for this reason so I know if will need to be on and have a sable internet connect. If I cannot then, what are some sites that are trusted for providing well secured SQL Servers.

I have TCP/IP enable but I cannot connect via IP given in the SQL Config. My ports are set correctly .

Thank you, I know this question is a little opinion based but I am new to this and would like to know what the 'pros' use. i.e. you guys...

Comment: SQL Server is a database server. SSMS is a management tool for connecting to and working with SQL Server. If you need a database then you need SQL Server (or some other database software). Why you would want to access it from the internet is another question. Generally when people develop web sites that need a database backend the database server is on the backend (in the internal network) and is not exposed directly to the internet.

Comment: @joeqwerty basically I just need the db to hold all the information and then access it. I understand that they are stored in 'tables' and I have done some research on them but I just need to make the server. So I need a program called "SQL Server" to host the server itself. Then connect to it via SSMS and manage it that way? I do have SQL config which shows that I have a "SQL Server (name)" running, is this what you are relating to?

Comment: Sure. You can use SQL Server. You could also use any one of several other database servers, such as MySQL, Oracle, DB2, Sybase, PostgreSQL, etc., etc.

Comment: Okay, but how do I then make it public available. E.I. I can edit the tables from anywhere? If you understand what I mean, if not, maybe we can start a chat. The root of my problem is that I can only edit while being on my home network, can I change that?

Comment: @joeqwerty ^^^ (forgot to tag you)

Answer (score 1):

It is a terrible idea to have your SQL server directly exposed to unwashed multitudes of the Internet. Instead you want to invest it what's called a ["3-Tier" architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-tier_architecture).

[image]

Your IIS server is the presentation tier and serves contact. The unwashed masses interact with your application here. Your application server sits in the logic tier and does what ever business logic your application requires. Your database server sits behind that protected and safe. From a security prospective the idea is that your web server can only talk to the application server and the application server can only talk to the database server.